# How to pass an object as an argument in a constructor of another class?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have this java program in which a list of person class is created... the dateofBirth is an object argument in person's class. Now i am facing a problem; how to initialize an object of person in list or how to pass the DateOfBirth object into Person's Constructor?

```
class DateOfBirth{
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    DateOfBirth(){
        this.year = 0;
        this.month = 0;
        this.day = 0;
    }

    DateOfBirth(int y, int m, int d){
        if(y>1900){
            year = y;
        }
        else{
            System.err.println("the year is too small too old" );           
        }
        if(0<month && month<13){
            month = m;
        }
        else{
            System.err.println("month should be within 1 to 12.");
        }
        if(0<day && day<30){            
            day = d;
        }           

    }


    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getMonth(){
         return month;
     }
    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

}
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private DateOfBirth Dob;

    public Person(String name, int age, DateOfBirth dob){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.Dob = dob;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public DateOfBirth getDob() {
        return Dob;
    }    

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}

public class MyList {
    ArrayList<Person> Personlist = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Person person=new Person("John",23,...) // how to pass the DateOfBirth object here?     

}
```

Comment: `Person person=new Person("John",23,new DateOfBirth(1990,10,10))`

Comment: Passion you should add your comment as an answer

Comment: by the way why to pass age when you have DOB in there .. calculate age based on DOB

Comment: btw, people are born on the 30th and 31st too :)

Comment: @Nevado however, you have to admit that this piece of code won't have issues with leap years. Which is a very common problem with most "do your own" date stuff. :P

Comment: @vlaz well this code will have problems with positive values for the `month` and the `year` as he checks if they are smaller than `0`. So i guess the leap year is the smaller problem here ;)

Comment: @KevinEsche erm, it's larger than 0, surely: `0 < 7 //true`

Comment: thank you for helping me... lots of details are not worked with...leap years, 30 and 31 of different months.
Also deducing the age from the **dateofbirth** ...@passion,

Answer (score 4):

Make a date first and then pass that as parameter

```
 public class MyList {
        ArrayList<Person> Personlist = new ArrayList<Person>();

DateOfBirth date = new DateOfBirth(2000, 1, 1);
    Person person = new Person("John", 16, date);

}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: you made a mistake,  Person person=new Person("John", 23, date); but +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Make object of DateOfBirth  where you need and then simply pass it to constructor like this

```
public class MyList {
        ArrayList<Person> Personlist = new ArrayList<Person>();

DateOfBirth dob= new DateOfBirth(1992, 2, 3);
    Person person=new Person("John",23,dob);

}
```

Comment: @TeunvanderWijst  was faster, sorry

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer of @TeunVanDerWijst you could also create another constructor in the class `Person` which would create the instance in the `Person` class itself. The constructor could look like the following.

```
public Person(String name, int age, int y, int m, int d) {
    this(name, age, new DateOfBirth(y, m, d));
}
```

The `this` would just call the other constructor which would then assign the freshly generated `DateOfBirth` instance.

Now you could create an instance of `Person` by just passing the year, the month and the day as `int`.

```
 Person person=new Person("John", 23, 2000, 9, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

if that dateofbirth is belongs to person you didn't need to create new DateOfBirth object

do it simple:

```
Person person = new Person("John",23,new DateOfBirth(1985,5,5));
```

or even like:

```
try
{
    Personlist.Add(new Person("John",23,new DateOfBirth(1985,5,5)));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //
}
```

for advice never use class names like MyList. 
list is collection, MyList is ??? new collection type ? what it has ??
try to make names that even if someone that didn't know what the program doing will understand the purpose.